# post preview/thumbnails not displaying correctly- linking to "home" instead of post?

Tags: permalinks, post-thumbnails, recent-posts, previews

[Live site](http://dyluxept.com)

In the lower portion of the landing page, I'd like there to be three blog post previews- just the headline and thumbnail for the three most recent posts. I'm using the following code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
    <div id="landing">
        <div id="intro">
            <h1>Hi, I'm Dylan Elchami-<br />a health and fitness enthusiast with a passion for inspiring.</h1>
            <p>My interests are vast and ever changing, but my virtues remain true. I love to motivate, create, make people healthier, stronger, sexier, and flat out better all while building great, unmitigated relationships along the way. Please roam my site and enjoy all the information I post for you, and if you have a question please don't hesitate to contact me- it's your way of giving back for all the free information because helping you is what makes me feel AWESOME.</p>
        </div><!-- end intro -->

        <div id="stay-in-touch">
            <p>Stay in touch-</p>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/facebook.png" alt="Like on Facebook" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/twitter.png" alt="Follow on Twitter" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/linkedin.png" alt="Connect on LinkedIn" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end stay-in-touch -->

        <div id="preview">
            <div id="preview-item">
                <div id="preview-headline">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
                </div><!-- end preview-headline -->
                <div id="preview-thumbnail">
                    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'nopaging' => true ) ); while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : ( $my_query->the_post() ); ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?> 
                </div><!-- end preview-thumbnail -->
            </div><!-- end preview-item --> 
        </div><!-- end preview-->
    </div><!-- end landing -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` in functions.php

As you can see on the site, the link where the previews should be says "Home" and doesn't have a thumbnail. How do I show the most recent 3 posts as previews and have them actually link to the post(not home)?

Comment: Do you have a second loop to call those 3 posts?  Otherwise your loop will only contain the current post (in this case, Home).

Comment: I do not, this is my first attempt at something like this which explains the issues/questions. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Do you have the same problem with **published** posts, or only with **draft/preview** posts?

Comment: @ChipBennett my only concern is with displaying published posts, which @SickHippie has helped me achieve. I am now having the issue of too many posts being displayed despite using `array( 'posts_per_page' => 3,`.

Comment: "*I am now having the issue of too many posts being displayed...*" - that's a **separate issue**, and should probably be posted as a **separate question**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a second loop on your home page to call the 3 most recent posts.  Try something like this:

```
// Main home page content here

<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'nopaging' => true ) );
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : ( $my_query->the_post() ); ?>
<div id="preview">
    <div id="preview-item">
        <div id="preview-headline">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
    </div><!-- end preview-headline -->
    <div id="preview-thumbnail">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(120,102) ); ?> 
    </div><!-- end preview-thumbnail -->
    </div><!-- end preview-item --> 
</div><!-- end preview-->
<?php endwhile; ?>

// Closing Home page content here
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the following code to no avail:

`<div id="preview">
     <div id="preview-item">
         <div id="preview-headline">
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
  </div><!-- end preview-headline -->
  <div id="preview-thumbnail">
      <?php $my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'nopaging' => true ) ); while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : ( $my_query->the_post() ); ?>
      <?php endwhile; ?> 
     </div><!-- end preview-thumbnail -->
 </div><!-- end preview-item --> 
 </div><!-- end preview-->`

What could be the prob?

Comment: You don't have anything during the `while` statement, so there won't be any changes.  Your code isn't actually doing anything.  Move your entire preview code block from your original post into the `while` statement, like I have in my post (updated).

Comment: I appreciate all of your help. I guess what's troubling me now is the fact that these previews will be on a statice page- there isn't dynamic content/a loop for me to insert the code you've given in.. unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying? I've edited my original post to show you exactly what I'm working with.

Comment: Please look at my updated post.  I've posted the code in the way it needs to be displayed.  Wrap your entire preview area while the `while`/`endwhile` section - that's the loop.  Anything between those two lines will be repeated for each item in the loop, which is limited to 3 by `posts_per_page`.  Think of it like this - `WP_Query` gets all the posts.  `while` says "for each item in this variable `$my_query` do whatever I say until `endwhile`.  I'll update my original post to be hopefully less confusing.

Comment: Again, thank you for your patience and help. If you click the link in my original post, you'll see that it now functions but is showing 4 posts despite having `array( 'posts_per_page' => 3,`. Any ideas on how to rectify this?

Comment: Not a problem - we were all new once.  Can you put this after the WP_Query call line and before the `while`?  `echo $post_count;` - that should tell us how many posts are in that particular loop.  I'm wondering if you've got a plugin that's overriding our query options or something.

Comment: So what I've got now is 
`<?php $my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'nopaging' => true ) );
echo $post_count;
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : ( $my_query->the_post() ); ?>`


I didn't notice a change in anything to indicate post numbers. As for the plugins, I've disabled everything but pageMash.

Comment: Remove it then, and add `wp_reset_query();` after `endwhile;`  That should kick that home link off.  Either way, there's some strange behavior going on there that really shouldn't be.  I can't really pick this up much right now, I have some other work to do.  Take a look at the WP_Query page on the Codex to get a feel for how it works, maybe you can get it sorted.  Otherwise, I'll be back later on and we can take this to chat.

Comment: If we could chat about this, that would be great. I really do appreciate you taking the time to help me get this worked out.